# Multiple tables need to have one-many relationship with common table

Tags: sql, database-design

Suppose, I have a SQL database with table like A,B,C and Z. all three table A,B and C has a one-many relationship with table Z. I think of solution mentioned below but need suggestion or better solution for this problem if any.

Solution-

- Create one more table named 'LinkZ' which have one-many relationship with table 'Z'
- Add foreign key field to table A,B and C of table 'LinkZ'
- So that way in future if more tables add to database which need relationship with table 'Z' we just need to add foreign key to newly added table of 'LinkZ' as it has already one-many relationship.

Please suggest solution if exist which satisfy my needs.

Edit -

@Gordon, "If all the tables have a "1-many" relationship with Z, then you don't need a link table at all. You need a link table when your relationships are many-to-many". I need this kind relationship which you have quoted from your answer. but if follow traditional way then i need to add AID, BID, CID in Z to achieve 1-Many with Z then 'Z' table contains many columns which represent foreign key with other table (In future might be other table also included to have same relationship, so in that case i want to avoid many columns from Z of only foreign keys only) that's why I have created dummy table 'LinkZ' which provide illusion to other table A,B and C that this all tables have 1-Many relationship with Z directly.

Comment: I agree with @gordonlinoff's answer that you probably don't need an intermediate "linking" table for this.  But I also agree with him that it's really unclear exactly what you are wanting to achieve.  But I bet you'd get an answer fast, either from me or somebody else, if you build an minimal example of your tables in an sql fiddle.

Comment: Your writing is not clear. Please give examples of everything you describe.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment.

If all the tables have a "1-many" relationship with Z, then you don't need a link table at all.  You need a link table when your relationships are many-to-many.

It is unclear which way the linkage is going, but you either want `ZID` in each of `A`, `B`, and `C`, or you want `AID`, `BID`, `CID` in `Z`.